# Jquery classList with hasClasses

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to add a .active class to every li element, but only if #books has the same classes/class as #post does.

But the classList function seems not to work with hasClasses function.

```
var classList =$('#post').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
});
$.fn.extend({
 hasClasses: function( selector ) {
    var classNamesRegex = new RegExp("( " + selector.replace(/ +/g,"").replace(/,/g, " | ") + " )"),
        rclass = /[\n\t\r]/g,
        i = 0,
        l = this.length;
    for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
        if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 && classNamesRegex.test((" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(rclass, " "))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
});
if ($('#books').hasClasses(classList)) {
$('li').addClass('active');
```

}

Comment: buuuuuuut... what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.is(".classA.classB.classC")`

If selector has multiple classes.. lets say

`<a href="#" class="link a b c">Some link</a>`

`$('.link').is('.a.b.c')` will return true.

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6rAga/)***

or as you wanted Use the below function `.hasClasses(["classA","classB","classC"])` to check if the selector has the list of classes. `hasClasses` takes an array of strings as an input.

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6rAga/10/)***

```
$.fn.extend({
    hasClasses: function (classArray) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var classList = '.' + classArray.join('.');
        console.log(classList);
        //Use .is() to check if the classes are present in the selector
        if ($this.is(classList)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

var classArray = $('#post').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
console.log("Comma separated classes:" + classArray);

var result = $('#post').hasClasses(classArray);

alert("Selector contains these classes? " + result);
```

Comment: also can use inarray if want to continue with your route https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: np - +1 for perfect answer.

Comment: So OP could use instead: `var classList = '.' + $('#post').attr('class').split(/\s+/).join('.');` and then: `if ($('#books').is(classList))` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/2dBTL/

Comment: @A.Wolff : exactly. I was coming up with the fiddle.

Comment: But what if i want to use the classList in the addClass selector:
$('classList').addClass('active');

Comment: @user2272278 in your question `classList` is an array not a selector. That's why I have changed the variable name in my answer to be `classArray`. You cannot write `addClass` to an array. You can push a class to the array like this `classList.push('active')`