# Jquery multiple classes with .addClass dynamically

Tags: jquery, split, addclass

I need to use .addCLass on an list of classes, but function classList gives me an array. .addClass doesn't work with array BUT it does  work if i write multiple classes, like ('.class1, class2, class3'). Is there a way to convert the .classList array to a string which can give to .addCLass. I need to get the classList dynamically hence I can't enter them manually...

Thanks

```
var classList = $('#postitus').attr('class').split(/\s+/).join('.');
$(classList).addClass('active');
```

Comment: can you give a sample value of `$('#postitus').attr('class')` and the desired output

Comment: wouldnt split(/\s+/).join('.'); give you 'foo.bar'? You should select $('.' + classList)

Comment: That wasn't answer you got yesterday for quite similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940278/jquery-classlist-with-hasclasses  You are forgetting to prepend dot. And checking for `classList` value should have shown you your issue, please debug on your side before posting duplicate-like question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/decbL/1/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/decbL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var classList = $('#postitus').attr('class').split(/\s+/);

$.each(classList,function(ind,val){
   $('.' +val).addClass('active');
} );
```

Comment: This one worked correctly, the ones above didn't work with my code. But, we have multiple #posititus divs, i need to get the classes from all of them. (I did change the #postitus to .postitus)

Answer (score 0):

`.split(/\s+/).join('.')` gives you "foo.bar.classes" which is not a valid selector, put a fullstop before:

```
$('.' + classList).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say just change your code a bit and you are sorted as

```
var classList = $('#postitus').attr('class').split(/\s+/).join(', .');
$('.' + classList).addClass('active');
```

And see in comments arunpjohny has updated fiddle for that as well, or see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/decbL/6/)